# Angle-preserving linear transformations in flat space

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-theory, invariance

I'm watching this [minutephysics video on Lorentz transformations](https://youtu.be/Rh0pYtQG5wI?t=133) (part starting from 2:13 and ending at 4:10). In my spacetime diagram, my worldline will be along the $ct$ axis and the worldline of an observer moving relative to me will be at some angle w.r.t. the $y$ axis.

When we switch to the other observer's spacetime diagram, the observer's worldline will be along the $y$ axis and my worldline would flip over to the other side, but the angle between the worldlines would be preserved. Then the video goes on to mention three possibilities:

[image]

The even at $(2,4)$ ends up getting mapped to $(0,T)$, where $T<4$, $T=4$ or $T>4$. And it seems like the video is suggesting only one possible transformation for each case, giving a total of only three possible transformations. For an angle preserving transformation $A$, given any two unit vectors $u_1,u_2$,

$$[u_1]^TM[u_2]=[u_1]^TA^TMA[u_2]\implies M=A^TMA$$

where $M$ is the metric we're assuming for the space. Seems like (though I'm not a 100% sure) the $T>4$ possibility corresponds to rotation (Euclidean, sure about this one), $T=4$ to Galilean boost (Galilean) and $T<4$ to Lorentz boost (Minkowski metric).

But why is it being suggested that **only** these three transformations (satisfying the angle preservation and linearity properties) are possible? Is it possible to find any other transformations than rotation for the case of $T>4$, or other than Lorentz for $T<4$, etc.? If not, can anyone direct me to a proof or explanation of why only three transformations are possible?

**Edit**: Specifically a mathematical argument/proof of why Euclidean, Galilean and Lorentz must be the only linear angle-preserving transformations in flat geometry.